# Variable has incomplete type 'struct sockaddr_in'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, compiler-errors

I try to use the

```
 struct sockaddr_in sin;
```

but if I use this I get

```
Variable has incomplete type 'struct sockaddr_in'
```

and

```
Forward declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in'
```

as Error.
I get error when I use Xcode4. In Xcode3.2 it works. 
Does someone know how to solve this error??
My imports are

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netinet6/in6.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
```

Comment: Are you actually spelling it `struck` in your code?

Comment: Nevermind, you said it works in Xcode 3.

Comment: I edited my Error, got a second one

Answer (score 3):

did you link your target with these two libraries?

- CFNetwork
- SystemConfiguration

[image]

Comment: Yes I did...    this seems to be some of this errors disappearing after some restarts of the mac and xCode... don't know how but the error disappeared ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `#import` rather `#include`.
`#import` ensures you never have a recursive include problem.

Tried and succeeded the same in `Xcode` 9.0.1, obj C. `iOS 11`

```
-SN
```